# stringsAsFactors = T or F

Tags: r, dataframe

I know in R this option is important as it decides whether you want to treat our vector (with characters) as a factor or purely plain text. But I wonder that, if say, my data frame has multiple vectors that use characters, for instance, "ppl_names" and "eye_colors". For ppl_names, I know it should be treated as plain text but for "eye_colors", it should be treated as a real factor due to the fact that it is a categorical data, right?

My questions is, when such case arises, how to handle it?

Comment: By default `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` from newer versions of R.  It was TRUE earlier.  Regarding whether to use as factor or character, it is up to the task you want.  Generally, character columns are more easier to handle, but if you want to keep some values in a particular order, then `factor` could help.  Also, it depends on some model criteria

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My concern is, when the data frame contains some vectors (say ppl's names or IDs that would usually not be considered as a factor/variable) but also some vectors (say colors, blood types) that would be considered as a factor (categorical factor/variable). How to use stringAsFactor to distinguish them?

Comment: If you are using `read.table/read.csv`, there is `colClasses` argument which can take a vector of class types based on the custom class you wanted.  Or another option is to convert the columns to a custom type after reading the data

Comment: If you use the default setting (`stringsAsFactors=FALSE`) then all the columns with character data will be character. Then identify which ones should be factors and convert them, `dfname$color <- factor(dfname$color)`. Read the manual page at `?factor` to see how to specify the order of the factor levels if you don't want them to be alphabetical.

Answer (score 3):

You can import with the default `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` and then use the `factor()` function to change relevant columns into factors.

```r
dat$eye_colors <- factor(dat$eye_colors)
```

If you want to quickly do this over more than one column you can use `lapply()`:

```r
# Create a list of column names that contain categorical data
categ_vrbs <- c("eye_colors", "nationality")

# Apply factor over these columns
dat[categ_vrbs] <- lapply(dat[categ_vrbs], factor)
```

Data:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
        ppl_names = c("John", "Akiko", "María Elena"),
        eye_colors = c("blue", "brown", "brown"),
        nationality = c("AUS", "JAP", "MEX")
           )
```